# When you have an AMD CPU, can you speed up code that uses the Intel-MKL?

Tags: performance, cross-platform, x86-64, intel-mkl, amd-processor

I have an AMD cpu and I'm trying to run some code that uses Intel-MKL. The code is significantly slower than I expected.

### When you have an AMD CPU, can you speed up code that uses the Intel-MKL? How?

Comment: Illustration of the problem with measurements: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62783262/5769463

Comment: FYI i tried to look up the old intel optimization notice but the previous link was not working. so i dug around and found a new intel optimization disclaimer [`Intel optimizations, for Intel compilers or other products, may not optimize to the same degree for non-Intel products.`](https://edc.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/performance/benchmarks/overview/). this new one is much more concise and readable (the old one was 10-20x longer, was an image containing text, and was written for lawyers (i.e. not layman)). it is disappointing that the old notice URL just stopped working tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE 2021-08-26: you can speed up older versions of MKL from before approximately 2020-08-31. Set the environment variable `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5` then run your code.

NOTE: I do not know the exact date or version when Intel removed the environment variable workaround.

FYI this slow down affects **anything** that uses Intel-MKL library and runs on AMD CPU (i.e. affects all operating systems and affects all programming languages and all programs ([older versions of Matlab](https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/dxn38s/howto_force_matlab_to_use_a_fast_codepath_on_amd/), C, C++, Python, Anaconda-Python, [Machine-Learning like Tensorflow and Pytorch](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/f2pbvz/discussion_workaround_for_mkl_on_amd/) , again **anything** that uses Intel-MKL library on AMD CPU)).

FYI Setting and getting environment variables is out of scope for this question but here are some helpful links:

- for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) and [another link with screenshots](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

  - personally i do: "old" control panel --> system --> advanced --> environment variables --> system variables --> ceate new
- for Linux [here is a general guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)

  - for the simple case of a `bash` user who wants to set the environment variable just for their own user append the line `export MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5` to your user's `.bashrc` file

---

---

---

p.s.

#### regarding the question "why/how does setting an environment variable cause code to run significantly faster?"

- The default behavior is for the Intel-MKL to check the CPU and run slower code if non-intel is detected.
- Setting the environment variable overrides the default behavior and causes the faster code to execute despite not having Intel hardware.

#### You are probably wondering "why would Intel have a software slow-down in their MKL library?

- Intel for many years had their compiled code check the CPU first then if the CPU was detected as non-intel the code would choose to run slower code
- there was a lawsuit
- a result of the lawsuit was that Intel had to disclose what they were doing but did not have to stop what they were doing
- here's the wiki page with more history and information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Reception

Comment: The detail, that the slow non-intel path uses SSE, while the faster path  (triggered by MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5) uses AVX2 is probably worth mentioning...

Comment: @ead Given that Intel-MKL is closed-source software, I can't look at the code and so I can't make any claims about specifics other than the observation that it runs slower.

Comment: There is no need to look into the code: `perf` tells everything one needs to know... While the trivia isn't uninteresting, it is too abstract to really understand what is the difference.

Comment: @ead i've never used `perf` so that's amazing you can figure out something like this using open-source tools.

Answer (score 5):

**As of 2021, Intel unfortunately [removed](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/ik4bt9/intel_recently_updated_their_cripple_amd_function/) the `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE`** to prevent people on AMD use the workaround presented in the accepted answer. This means that the workaround no longer works, and AMD users have to either switch to OpenBLAS or keep using MKL.

**To use the workaround, follow this method**:

1. Create a `conda` environment with `conda`'s and NumPy's MKL=2019.
2. Activate the environment
3. Set `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE` = 5

The commands for the above steps:

1. `conda create -n my_env -c anaconda python numpy mkl=2019.* blas=*=*mkl`
2. `conda activate my_env`
3. `conda env config vars set MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5`

**And thats it!**

Comment: (I have not confirmed.) whoa. Intel removing this is significant move by Intel against AMD IMO. thanks for the update... very important news if true.

Comment: Yes, this is very disappointing for scientists using AMD CPUs. And it doesn't look like Intel is ever gonna give up on "crippling" AMD, in my opinion. My miniconda python uses MKL 2020.3, and I haven't figured out how to get over the "cripple AMD" function, despite searching for weeks.