# How come xgboost is significantly slower on my better computer?

Tags: python, linux, scikit-learn, xgboost

xgboost is performing very slowly for my more powerful computer for xgboost in particular.

Weaker computer specs:

- Windows 10, python 3.9.7 (jupyter), pandas 1.3.5, sklearn 1.0.2, xgboost 1.5.1
- 16GB RAM, Intel i7-10870H

Powerful computer specs:

- Ubuntu, python 3.9.5,  pandas 1.4.0, sklearn 1.0.2, xgboost 1.5.2
- 32GB RAM, AMD Ryzen 5900

The following code took 2.7 minutes for my powerful computer vs. 1.1 minute for my weaker computer. The performance difference is even more terrible (~30x slower) when using sklearn's cross validation classes that utilize multiprocessing.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import xgboost as xgb
import datetime

iris = load_iris()

x = iris.data
y = iris.target

start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start)
for i in range(1000):
    mdl2 = xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=.15
                             , max_depth=9
                             , min_child_weight=1
                             , min_split_loss=.1
                             , colsample_bytree=.5
                             , scale_pos_weight=.46)
     
    mdl2.fit(x, y)

finished = ((datetime.datetime.now() - start).seconds/60)
print(finished)
```

Update #1: I suspect the AMD CPU is not so compatible with xgboost compared to Intel. I am buying Intel's i9 12900 and will update in ~1 week

Update #2: While performance improved a lot switching from AMD Ryzen 9 5900 to Intel's i9 12900 (2.7 minutes to 1.8 minutes), I am still having the issues where the weaker computer is outperforming (1.1 minutes). Maybe xgboost is not so good for linux, and/or the modern high-end CPUs. I'll note again this is only xgboost (not sklearn models). I also noted that the cpu temperature is unexpectedly cold during training (~40C), so the system is obviously not pushing the CPU's potential.

Update #3: I installed Windows 10 and anaconda on the powerful computer and ran the above code and it completed in 0.86 minutes. So apparently xgboost is optimized for Windows 10 over Ubuntu

Comment: Have you compared any other installed packages? Maybe different compilers were used? Did you install everything yourself from source? Pip? Conda? That all might matter a lot!

Comment: Other functions (like sklearn's decisionTreeClassifier) and basic loops are completing as expected. It seems to be an xgboost problem.

Comment: It's typical for GPU acceleration to take some work to get functioning correctly on Linux, rather than behaving correctly out-of-the-box. If CUDA is in use here, that brings quite a lot of potential issues requiring in-depth investigation (of exactly which drivers are in use; file permissions for relevant devices; etc) into scope. That said, I've only glanced momentarily at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gpu/index.html rather than read it enough to know if your specific code would be using CUDA were the system correctly configured.

Comment: (also, the question doesn't say anything at all about whether the "weaker" computer has a CUDA-capable GPU in the first place).

Comment: (and yes, as PrinsEdje80 said, what CPU the binaries on each system were compiled to assume as the minimum compatible support can make a big difference -- it doesn't matter if you have a CPU that offers a bunch of extensions that improve pipelining if the software isn't built to use them! This is one of the rationales behind Linux distros that build from source, to ensure everything is built for your specific hardware and able to take advantage of its full capabilities)

Comment: (...not that I'm personally recommending using a source-based distro, especially if you haven't verified that (non)use of CPU extensions is the source of your performance delta; personally, I use NixOS, which locally builds only binaries for which no exact match is cached, so you can ask it to use a different set of compiler flags for only one specific package, and it'll do a local build only if there's no precached binary built with those name flags).

Comment: It's true my GPU for the powerful computer is terrible, but I'm near certain this code doesn't utilize GPU

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you add the frequency of AMD and GPU config of both devices?

Comment: likely related - are you getting BLAS from anaconda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174453/when-you-have-an-amd-cpu-can-you-speed-up-code-that-uses-the-intel-mkl

Answer (score 2):

to make sure you are using the same libraries on both systems; I suggest using `pip freeze`. Just do `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` on PC with a lower execution time to copy.

Then on the target computer create a virtual environment and do `pip install requirements.txt`. In this way, you will install the same packages all at once.

However, one guess to explain the performance difference is that; the algorithm might need high-frequency single cores, rather than much lower frequency AMD cores. So, it might be the reason for lower performance on AMD devices.

**UPDATE**:

I experienced the same issue on two systems that I have: I used `sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep "Speed"` to get CPU speed
MAX possible shows the maximum speed when overclocked)

PC1:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 server
377GB RAM, 
2CPUs: 96cores in sum with  Max Speed: 4500 MHz Current Speed: 2200 MGHz
lscpu model name: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5220R CPU @ 2.20GHz`
nvcc -V: 11.0
```

PC2:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
31GB RAM, 
12 cores    Max Speed: 8300 MHz Current Speed: 3200 MHz
lscpu: model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
nvcc -V: 10.1
```

to be fair about the comparison I made a new Conda environment with python `3.9.7` and installed the following versions on both:

```
certifi==2021.10.8
DateTime==4.4
joblib==1.1.0
numpy==1.22.2
pandas==1.4.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
xgboost==1.5.2
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Other points: all CPU cores for both tests were 90%+, according to `htop`

Finally:
with `python testXGboost.py`

PC1: `3.7 ~ 4.7` s

PC2:  `0.93 ~ 1.04`  s

with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 python testXGboost.py`:

PC1: `~ 13.5`

PC2:  `4.7`

I think one reason is that the per-core clock is more important in XGBoost performance than core count. The second is that it turns out XGboost might automatically use GPU to some extent. So, these two explain (probably) why the performance is different on your two PCs.

Comment: python is independent of the operating system I believe, So it is worth doing pip freeze and transfer to the other system and retry. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: "Independent"... only down to a point. xgboost isn't written in pure Python -- it's using native, compiled libraries under the hood, just as numpy does. Particularly for this magnitude of performance delta, I'd expect it to be something along the lines of CUDA acceleration not being accessible, and that's very much an OS configuration issue -- or just those C libraries not being compiled with the local CPU's vectorization instruction support enabled at the compiler level. In this respect, Python is a lot more OS-dependent than Java is, since Java gets JITted for the local instruction set.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy checkout my updated answer.

Comment: I suspect it's the AMD CPU too. I'm buying an Intel i9 12900KF (roughly equivalent beast but i suspect better tuned for xgboost), and will update

Comment: Solid investigation w/ the update.

Comment: I have the same issue. I run same model with multiple hyperparameters simultaneously with multiprocessing.Process. On my laptop with i7-1260p running with 8 threads (well Processes) I get around 200 results/minute, while on Ryzen 9 5950x with 32 Processes I get like 1 in 5 minutes(!!!). The same dataset trained with GradientBoostingRegresor gives me around 500 results/minute so that is +- the result I'd expect. Some major AMD incompatibility issue there :(

On AMD I run it in docker, but with the same python and packages version.